# Assembly how to check result of scasb

Tags: assembly, x86

I have to find the (beginning) positions of a substring in a string. I load the string byte by byte in `AL` and compare it using `SCASB`. How can I check if the bytes are equal or if `SCASB` is true?

```
        clc
        scasb ;compare the value from al with <es:di>
              ;al is loaded from <ds:si>(lodsb)
              ;I noticed that when the values are equal
              ;cf and af are 1
        jnc nextElem ;if cf is 0 go to the next element

        lahf
        cmp  ah,0
        je nextElem ;if af is 0 go to next elem
```

The problem is that `LAHF` doesn't bring the value that I expected in ah, meaning is not 0 or 1, and I don't know any other way to check if the values in `AL` and  are equal.

Comment: Mention some more details.

Comment: First sentence of documentation for the `scasb` instruction: "SCASB compares the byte in AL with the byte at [ES:DI] or [ES:EDI], and sets the flags accordingly." If you want to check for equality, then use ZF. CF is for testing if less than.

Comment: @TirthrajBarot I added some code in the question. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @RaymondChen I tried but the zf doesn't change so it just goes on even if the values are different..

Comment: Why are you using LAHF in the first place?  Why not just branch on a condition since you already have the flags you want in EFLAGS.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code a bit and this is it:

```
mov  cx,length  ; length of the substring
repe cmpsb      ; compare <ds:si> with <es:di> 
jcxz Pozitie    ; if cx is zero than we found the substring in the string
```

Comment: REPE CMPSB also leaves flags set, and JCC on flags is usually more efficient than JCXZ (e.g. [2 uops instead of 1 on Intel SnB-family.  Nowhere near as bad as LOOP, though](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35742570/224132).  I haven't tested this, but `JNE Pozitie` should be an exact replacement for JCXZ here, true only if `repe cmpsb` stopped early.

Answer (score 1):

If you want not using jump instruction and you use "RepNE ScaSB" string instruction, to find the offset of the previous don't matching character (CX), you may write:

```
 ClD             {Clear string direction flag}

 XOr   AL,AL     {Set AL's reg. with the character to find (0)}
 Mov   CX,0FFFFH {Set CX's reg. with maximum length of the string}

 RepNE ScaSB     {Search null and decrease CX's reg.}

 LAHF            {Load FZero flag into AH (Bit6)}
 Not   CX        {Set CX with the number of char scanned}
 ShL   AH,1      {...}
 ShL   AH,1      {... FCarry is set with (FZero after scan)}
 SbB   CX,0      {If it founds 0 decrease CX's reg.}
```

If CX=65535 you haven't found the character.

Hi!

Comment: `shl ah, 2` would be more efficient (except on Intel P6-family, where using the flag-result of an imm8 shift will stall).  This isn't an 8086-only question (although it does seem to be 16-bit).  Also, can you stop putting "Hi!" at the bottom of your answers?  Stack Overflow doesn't allow signature lines.

Comment: Can you `setz al` or `setnz al` / `sub ax, cx` or something?  (If you zeroed the whole AX/EAX before scasb, instead of just AL).  There's probably another + or - 1 or something needed there to account for NEG vs. NOT 2's complement.

Answer (score 0):

`Scasb`, `cmpsb` are useful only when used on strings, with length/counter in CX register. Here is `strstr` implemented in 8086 asm:

http://techref.massmind.org/techref/language/asm/x86/stdlib/STRSTR.ASM

The idea is to use `scasb` with repne prefix (repeat while not equal) to find first char of substring in string. if found, rest of the string is compared using `repe cmpsb`.

Comment: You would better show an actual example rather than providing this link!

Comment: well the author(s) explicitly asked "PLEASE DON'T RIP! DO: LINK", it is on the top of the page :)

Comment: I don't agree that `scasb`, ... are only useful when used on strings with length in `CX` register. `scasb` and friends came perfectly operate without using the `CX` register.

Comment: Even so. If the author doesn't permit copying, then invent an example of your own.